# Receive empty object in node js express request

Tags: node.js, express, post, react-native, fetch

I have a problem when i upload image from react native to node js server, this is my code

Client

```
var url = "http://192.168.55.120:3000/uploadimg";
var file = this.state.imgsrc.uri;
const data = new FormData();
data.append('token', 'testName'); 
data.append('photo', {
  uri: file,
  type: 'image/jpeg', 
  name: 'testPhotoName'
});
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  body: data
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

and my server code

```
const   express         = require('express'),
        bodyParser      = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/uploadimg', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // =====> empty object       
})
```

My code is wrong ?

Comment: multer is the package you will need to handle multipart/form-data https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer and the image file will be in `req.file` or `req.files`

Comment: Maybe i will try your solution, thank you, please post answer, i will vote up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check in [`body-parser` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), this package doesn't handle multipart form data bodies.

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> ```
> busboy and connect-busboy
> multiparty and connect-multiparty
> formidable
> multer
> ```

Also, you shouldn't need to specify the content type header in `fetch`; it'll handle it for you depending on the provided body.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `stringify` the `formData` as mentioned in their [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)

> Using the FormData API is the simplest and fastest, but has the disadvantage that data collected can not be stringified.
>
> If you want to stringify a submitted data, use the pure-AJAX method.

You may consider trying it with [`util-inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)